# Are there examples of affirmative action (or equivalent) being applied to White groups?

Tags: discrimination, affirmative-action

In [Does the VRA require drawing districts for white people in majority-minority states?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/68115/does-the-vra-require-drawing-districts-for-white-people-in-majority-minority-sta) it was asked if the Voting Rights Act could be applied to white minorities any time soon and the answer seems to be no. This got me curious - are there any examples (in the US or some other country) where affirmative action was applied to a White minority? A hypothetical example would include White students in China being granted free tuition because they’re underrepresented in local universities.

The definition of "White" for me is the same as in the US Census: "having origins in any of the original peoples of Europe, the Middle East or North Africa."

Comment: The US census definition is relevant in the US, not necessarily readily applicable everywhere.

Comment: Possibly interesting: https://munin.uit.no/bitstream/handle/10037/6478/thesis.pdf?isAllowed=y&sequence=2

Comment: Ambiguity in the question (does not affect my answer  but may affect someone else's): Given the ongoing (and near-constant) cultural and governmental  strife in parts of  the Middle East and the ongoing refugee program in places like Syria, if an entity were to institute an affirmative action program in favor of middle eastern people principally (but not officially, as in it doesn't say this anywhere in writing) based on their refugee status, would that count as an answer to this question?  I feel like the spirit of the question says no, but the letter of  the question says yes.

Comment: @Ertai87 it would count if and only if the program is restricted to persons of a certain race. So if a Black Syrian can apply for the same benefits, it wouldn't count.

Comment: Does SA Apartheid count as "or equivalent", or is motivation also a relevant factor?

Comment: @Peter the apartheid is technically an extreme example of “affirmative action” but since the SA government was completely white it doesn’t count.

Comment: Would this apply e.g. to Irish speakers in Ireland, or speakers of other minority languages in other European countries? Would they be classed as an ethnic group?

Comment: @StuartF only if it’s a classification that’s assigned at birth rather than something dependent on a persons skills.

Comment: @JonathanReez Is affirmative action in favour of Sami people in (white-majority) Scandinavian countries relevant to your question? The origin of the Sami people is not clear, but modern genetic research suggests that they for the most part [originated in Europe](https://www.laits.utexas.edu/sami/dieda/hist/genetic.htm), and would therefore fulfil your definition of "white". And legally, Sami are considered "indigenous people" in Scandinavian countries.

Comment: Certain universities in India have reserved seats for Jewish people. The Parliament had two seats reserved for Anglo-Indians until recently. The University of Kerala and the Cochin University of Science and Technology both have Jew quotas. However, there are hardly any Anglo-Indian people in India, and far fewer Jews, and I do not imagine that either are considered backward or victims of structural discrimination. So can't really call it AA.

Comment: @AravindSuresh What is the rationale behind quotas for Jews, then?

Comment: Not going to bother with an answer but "origins in the middle East" would make it true for a number of ME countries that have such status/bonus for some minorities... which are from the same region. But not because they are "White". Also, regarding Apartheid-like stuff, some African colonies had mixed governments, not just whites, but whites were favored, e.g. IIRC, Congo Free State.

Comment: The Soviet Union might also have had something like this... https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.7591/9781501713323-008/html

Comment: I guess the main point of unclarity/leeway in your Q is if the majority in the country has to be non-White (using US standards), and additionally if you're talking just about statistical majority of the whole population or the majority of the (true) powerholders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is [affirmative action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirmative_action_in_China) in the People's Republic of China, which targets [the 55 officially recognised ethnic minorities in China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnic_minorities_in_China), including the [Russian minority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russians_in_China), who are of European origin.

According to the linked Wikipedia article, the policies of the affirmative action include/included things such as:

> Minority students applying to universities receive bonus points on the National Higher Education Entrance Examination (gaokao)

> The government established bilingual programs to help minorities learn Mandarin Chinese

> The Chinese government officially allowed minority parents to have more than one child per family instead of the one demanded for Han people as part of the (former) one-child policy

The above policies apply to all officially recognised ethnic minorities, including, but not limited to the Russian minority.

[This page](https://www.uoowu.com/qinggan/1371009.html) provides some details on bonus points for the Russian minority. Here is an automated translation of the first question and answer:

> Do Russians get extra points for the college entrance exam?

> For ethnic minority candidates from ethnic autonomous counties and ethnic townships who apply for the Chinese language-taught general institutions of higher learning, 20 points will be added for the cultural course when they are admitted.

Answer (score 7):

It's very difficult to prove a negative, as there is no comprehensive listing  of every single program endorsed  by every single organization in the world anywhere, and if there was then it would be prohibitively long  to scan.  Therefore, giving a negative answer to this question is  difficult to factually back up.  However, Wikipedia has a pretty decent listing as a good  place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirmative_action

Looking through Wikipedia, the only countries with official affirmative action  programs/laws are majority-white locales, with the exceptions of  the listed locales in Asia: China, Israel, India, Indonesia, Malaysia, Sri Lanka, Taiwan.  Ignoring Israel,  because it is a majority "white" country (in that its population is majority Jewish people descendant from "white" denominations (under the US Census definition), those primarily being the 3 tribes of Ashkenazi (Eastern Europe), Sephardi (Spain), and Mizrachi (Middle East)), we have:

(Paraphrasing from Wikipedia)

- China: Affirmative  action in favor of "ethnic minorities", which Wikipedia defines as "non-Han".  This  is basically a blanket  statement including anyone  who is not "Han Chinese", which is a subgroup of Chinese  people.  In theory this could include  white people, but  is probably not what is being asked about.  **No**.
- India: Affirmative action is based on the Indian historical caste system, to try to  raise people  of "lower"  castes upwards in society.  This is not  racially based  and would not  affect white people.  **No**.
- Indonesia: Affirmative action in favor of an ethnic indigenous group in the Indonesian region.  **No**.
- Malaysia: Affirmative action in favor of ethnic Malaysians to help boost them in relation to the Indian and Chinese populations.  **No**.
- Sri Lanka: Affirmative action based on cultural origin, specifically the Tamil population.  Not based on race, so  **No**.
- Taiwan: Affirmative action in favor of  aboriginal  Taiwanese.  **No**.

Therefore, at least in the scope of the examples that Wikipedia cares to list on their page on the topic, the answer appears to be that no, there are no official widespread affirmative  action programs in favor of white people anywhere in parts of the world where white people  are minorities.

Comment: The majority of Israelis are of Mizrachi and Sephardi descent (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israelis#Jews).  Therefore, your assertion of Israel as majority "white" is incorrect.  It is more correct to say that Israel is culturally "white", due to the historical dominance of Ashkenazim within Israel's power structures and the powerful influence of Socialism upon Israel's founding id.eology (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labor_Zionism)

Comment: @Moshe If you look a the chart on the page you linked,  sorting decending order by percentage, the top percentages, aside from "Israel" itself (which is like myself saying I am Canadian; my lineage in the last 100 years is in Canada but before that it was elsewhere), the top 2 percentages are Europe/Americas/Oceania and Soviet Union, which together total 48.9%.  Add in Romania and Poland down the list which total 7.2%, and you have "white majority".

Comment: Not so.  "Israel itself" is primarily Mizrachi.  The state has only existed for 73 years.  Intermarriage is now rampant, thank God, but it will take at least another century for "Israeli" to become a truly coherent identity in itself.  Same is true of culture.  There is only the beginning of a single coherent culture.  We've all been apart 2000 years.  This family reunion is a messy business.  It takes time.

Comment: China lists Russians as ethnic minority (they had some villages on their side of the border I believe) so you may assume they have positive discrimination for a tiny amount of people who look european.

Comment: @alamar Read my caveat in the answer.  I noted that white people may be included in "ethnic minorities" that China's affirmative action laws covers, but that's probably not included in the spirit of the question.

Comment: In addition to Moshe's point (about majority of Israeli-born being Mizrachi), why do you assume that an overwhelming majority of American-born Jews are white?  The Ashkenazi are, but there have been waves of Sephardic immigrations to the US as well.

Comment: @wrod Sephardis have their origin in Spain; the US Census definition of "white" includes all of Europe, and last I checked Spain was part of Europe.  Therefore, Sephardis are also white.  Note also that Mizrahi Jews, defined by Wikipedia as descendant of Middle Eastern people, are also "white" by the same definition.  So yeah, the overwhelming majority of American Jews are white.

Comment: Updated the answer to put an end to the "Jews aren't white" discussion.

Comment: @Ertai87 not really anymore.  Not since 1492.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sephardi_Jews) defines sephardim as "Hispanic Jews."  Which effectively means Jews with strong roots from Spain's former colonies.  Hispanics are not considered "white" under the US census rules.  By Canada's demographic rules they would be "metiso."

Comment: @Ertai87 What makes you think that white minority groups in China are "probably not included in the spirit of the question"? I cannot understand your reasoning.

Comment: @wrod Wait...are you claiming Spain is not part of Europe?  Because the US Census definition of "white" is "anyone from Europe" (plus other things).  So if you're saying that Sephardim have Spanish roots, and they are therefore not white, then you are saying Spain is not part of Europe, and that's a pretty bold claim...

Comment: @michau In general, affirmative action laws have a specific goal, to enhance the specific status of a specific group.  OP is asking (in my estimation of the question) if there are any affirmative action laws targeted at whites.  While "non-Chinese" does indeed include white people, one would be hesitant to say that a law which affects black people (who are also non-Chinese) as much as it affects white people, is targeted at whites.  That's my reading of the question, OP can edit the question or comment in the thread under this answer if he would like to clarify his intent.

Comment: @Ertai87 wow, had to re-read my comment.  Nope, it is as I thought.  I did not, in fact, claim that Spain is not a part of Europe.  Anyone who was born in Latin America qualifies as "Hispanic" for the purposes of the US Census.  And so does anyone who has any such ancestors.  And yes that means that 2 Spaniads who moved to Mexico and had a child would have child who is "Hispanic" by these rules.  I am not making the rules.  It's just what they happen to be.  "Hispanics" in the US are a very, very broad spectrum of ethnicities.

Comment: @Ertai87 oh, and as a "btw," in case you think the rules don't make sense, I personally know sephardic Jews who consider themselves ethnically "mexican" despite having been born in the US.  And in most crowds they mix in, that's how they are viewed, too.  Metisos, in general, are a very wide range of ethnicities.

Comment: @wrod Sure.  In any case, the stipulation claim that Moshe made above was with respect to Israel being composed primarily of Mizrachi Jews, not Sephardic Jews, which are (according to Wikipedia) of Middle Eastern descent, who would also be considered "white" by the US Census.

Answer (score 2):

Frame shift:  where do you see this both being necessary and to be expected?

- a white minority *that is doing badly*
- a government that is well-run *and* compassionate enough to run ethnically-based affirmative action-like programs?
- a government that recognizes race-based criteria in a positive sense

Starting with the last, a number of European states don't allow racial data in official statistics.  France is the one I am most familiar with.

Second, I wouldn't expect a dictatorship or some really corrupt country to run this kind of program.  So, just to take an example off the top of my head, Zimbabwe is straight out.  Japan is well run but not particularly known for going out of its way to support other ethnic groups.

And finishing with the first, from the small list of countries that are left, in most cases whites are either a majority or a somewhat prosperous minority.

If in the future whites do become a significant badly-off minority in some well-run political entities *that use affirmative action*, well, yes, I would expect the same sense of justice (as well as self-interest not to entrench permanent poor, hence low-tax-value, underclasses) that motivated affirmative action to apply to that white minority.

If it didn't it would undermine the justification for having affirmative action in the first place.  Is it about making the country as a whole better off or taking revenge for past misdeeds?

But for now this remains a somewhat hypothetical, if interesting, question.

p.s. Driving everything from guilt isn't super-productive.  As a European, white, non-British (French, actually), 1st-gen immigrant to Canada, I am willing to consider the guilt of what was done to indigenous people *by the British*.  After all, most European colonial powers exhibited beastly behaviors in their colonies, so there is a sense of "solidarity" between us.

But Canada is becoming ever more ethnically-mixed.  If Europeans become a minority in a province, should you expect say Asian-descent Canadians to take on the tax burden of paying for "white guilt"?  Why not vote out those affirmative action programs toward indigenous people?  You need a more *positive* and forward-looking justification for those programs, intended to *help* people.

Comment: Anecdotally speaking from personal experience, Japan is precisely the type of country where I would expect some sort of white-centric affirmative action, if it were to exist anywhere.  It is a country with a very large non-white ethnic majority, with a lot of barriers to entry for those outside that majority (language being the largest one but far from the only), with a more-or-less Western-like set of values, with a fairly large white minority (inasmuch as Japan has a large minority of anything, which it  doesn't), most of whom work low-skill low-wage jobs (mostly as English teachers).

Comment: That said, as you made reference to, the Japanese government really kind  of doesn't give a single fuck about any minority group; their position on all this sort of stuff can mostly be described as "if you want to live in our country, you will do what you need to do to live here without our direct interference, or you won't be able to live here".  There are additional cases where Japan has instituted policies against foreigners as well (I don't know the details, but something about foreigners receiving a Japanese public pension was a big one a while back)

Comment: @Ertai87: Are English teachers in Japan really "low-skill low-wage" jobs?  Having known several (when I was learning the language), it always seemed more of a way to live in the country for a few years and get your expenses covered.

Comment: @jamesqf Of the people I know who at one point or another moved to Japan to teach English, more of them turned it into a life-career than didn't, and of those, almost all of them do not have an "employable" university degree (e.g. STEM), and also almost all of them eventually got married to a Japanese person who had a "real" job to support them financially; one example is a friend of mine who was an English teacher for 15+ years who married a VP at Toyota.

Comment: Also, speaking from personal experience, English teaching in Japan is more-or-less minimum wage, inasmuch as Japan has a minimum wage (which it kind of doesn't; legally it does but it's almost impossible to find a job which pays that much, you will almost always get more, although the minimum wage in Japan I think is $6/hr so "more" does not necessarily mean much).  Based on research I did (about 10 years ago), annual salary for a foreign English teacher in Japan is roughly $30-40k/yr (adjusted by cost-of-living), although it might have increased over the last decade.

Comment: That said, you are 100% correct in that many of the programs intended to get foreigners to Japan to teach English, and in particular the more prestigious ones (e.g. JET) are specifically intended to be temporary, as you said.  However, it tends not to play out that way.  The way it commonly plays out is that, once one contract is over, the teacher will simply take up a new contract with another company; there are copious companies in Japan which will hire any foreigner who doesn't need visa/relocation assistance (who will not hire those who do need assistance).

Comment: @Ertai87: I could be working from a biased sample, since the ones I knew were those who had returned to the US.

Answer (score 0):

The soviet union was a pioneer of affirmative action with a [policy known as Korenizatsiya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korenizatsiya). This aimed to promote the cultural and political interests of non-Russian minorities within the USSR such as the Ukrainians.

> The de-Russification was also implemented on ethnic Russian groups and their children. For example, all children in Ukraine were taught the Ukrainian language in school. The policies of korenization facilitated the Communist Party's establishment of the local languages in government and education, in publishing, in culture, and in public life.

Affirmative action in the USSR also included prioritizing minorities including Ukrainians [for political appointments and other government jobs](https://blogs.cuit.columbia.edu/rightsviews/2017/11/07/soviet-affirmative-action-and-contemporary-inclusion-of-minorities/)

Since Ukrainians would be considered white, I believe this example meets your criteria.

Answer (score -2):

Title, boldface added:

> Are there examples of affirmative action (**or equivalent**) being applied to White groups?

From text of question:

> ...This got me curious - are there any examples (in the US or some other country) where affirmative action was applied to a White minority?

Re "or equivalent":

Slavery applied many affirmative advantages to a White minority of people-owners.

As did Jim Crow laws, and thousands of once-legal forms of racist discrimination.

As do the Jim Crow 2.0 voting laws the emergence of which the VRA was designed to combat.

Comment: Slavery only conferred advantages on slave owners, not all of whom were white.  (In the US, moreso if you consider the rest of the world.) It was arguably disadvantageous to the majority of whites (and free blacks &c) who didn't own slaves.  Likewise, the various "Jim Crow" laws didn't confer any material advantages, AFAIK.

Comment: @jamesqf, Slavery conferred advantages on slave owners, slave owner's families, and their households, (which could be quite large), plus slaves could be rented out like a power tool, which conferred advantages on the slave owner's peers and projects.  For example, if rented slaves built a splendid college campus, (whites only), its students and their families had the exclusive enjoyment and benefit of the fruits of slave labor... even if no student nor family member owned a slave.

Answer (score -4):

Let's be perfectly clear... Institutions like the Voting Rights Act and Affirmative Action were ***not*** created to help minorities. They were created to remedy the systematic political, social, and economic disempowerment — disenfranchisement, segregation, red-lining, barred access to workplaces and financial resources, etc. — that certain groups have historically been subject to. One doesn't need to the concept of 'race' to understand that systematic social and economic alienation can pose excess risks, burdens, and obstacles to groups trying to make their way in society, and we only need to look at the case of *women* to realize that a group can have a numerical majority and *still* be subject to such alienation. Framing this as a minority/majority issue is disingenuous at best.

Institutions like the Voting Rights Act and Affirmative Action address **power**, and the way that a group with power can use their power to further *dis*empower other groups. If it's a stepladder, it's a stepladder meant to help people climb out of the generations-deep hole that's been dug for them, so they can climb up to something like a level playing field.

Since perhaps the 16<sup>th</sup> century, whites of European descent have held hegemonic political, social, and economic power over most of the world. There are places where their influence is weaker (such as China, Japan, and the Koreas), and places where they have left or been driven out (as in India and much of Africa) but there isn't any corner of the world where whites of European descent have been systematically oppressed and disempowered. As a matter of objective history, whites have always dug holes to push *other* people into. Why would we give a ladder to some group that's already standing at the top?

Comment: If you count Jews as "white" (the US census does), there's certainly been a lot of systemic discrimination against them in Europe and the US.

Comment: More examples include: Armenians (Turkey and Azerbaijan), Kurds (Turkey), Assyrians (Iraq), Albanians (Kosovo). [The list goes on and on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ethnic_cleansing_campaigns). Your answer is very much US-centric.

Comment: *there isn't any corner of the world where whites of European descent have been systematically oppressed and disempowered* Ever heard of Zimbabwe?  That's not a point to support the OPs question, as I don't see Zimbabwe being well run or using affirmative action in any other way than to support cronyism by party members.  In which case it's not affirmative action, just corruption and that's a much older gig.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: As I understand it, Zimbabwe was under white minority rule until the 1980s, and after white minority rule ended there was no explicit oppression or disenfranchisement of whites. There was redistribution — whites were a fairly small minority by numbers but controlled the vast majority of property, wealth, and resources in the nation — but that redistribution was part of the agreement worked out during the transition to (ostensibly) democratic rule. The hardly counts.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: The point is that institutions like this are *remedies* not *gifts*. Historically speaking, whites of European descent are the *cause* of the problems that need remedy; never the subject of those problems.

Comment: @JonathanReez Seems a very big streeeetch to use Jewish people to make a point about white people getting oppressed, when you consider the ethnicity of those doing the oppressing of said Jewish people all the way through 1945, culminating with the Holocaust.  That's just a bizarre argument.  For the rest,  many of the ethnic groups you cite - Iraqis, Albanians, Kurds - wouldn't exactly be welcomed with open arms by the average European country either and in most cases your events concern white-by-white persecutions in the first place.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica my point was that ethnic groups of any skin color have routinely been oppressed throughout history. There's also [plenty of examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Liberia#Americo-Liberian_and_indigenous_segregation_(1847%E2%80%931940)) of black-on-black oppression.

Comment: @JonathanReez: I think we still need to see a credible example of Christian Caucasians being systematically disenfranchised and oppressed. Historically they have always been in the role of oppressor, so far as I can tell. I mean, it's not as though an Asian or African nation colonized (say) Sweden, and forced Swedes to work on plantations or mine ores and precious metals.

Comment: @TedWrigley [here's one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copts#Persecution_and_discrimination_in_Egypt). For an example of what Copt Egyptians look like, [see Rami Malek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rami_Malek). There has also been numerous persecution and conflicts between Protestant, Catholic and Orthodox branches of Christianity within Europe.

Comment: @JonathanReez: Copts are not of Caucasian descent; They dislike being identified as a Semitic ethnicity, or so I understand, but they are ancestrally north-east Africans. You keep trying to squish pale-skinned ethnic groups into the Caucasian category, so that it appears as though Caucasians might have been victims *somewhere*, but I suspect that both the ethnic groups and white ethnonationalists would strenuously object.

Comment: @TedWrigley [that's what the US Census](https://www.census.gov/topics/population/race/about.html) says "white" is. But if you narrow things down to Whites originating from mainland Europe (so EU, UK, Western Russia, Ukraine, Belarus) and discrimination happening outside of Europe, then yes, Whites are not oppressed anywhere for now.

Comment: @Ted Wrigley: Seems your problem is that you are seeing all "white" people as the same, when that's emphatically not so.  Consider the status of Irish & Italians in the late 19th & early 20th century US.  Or poor white "hillbillies" in Appalachia.  Or for a more international & historic example, you might consider the English occupation of Ireland, and to a lesser extent Scotland & Wales.